# How i can use multiple divs with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i'm Trying to use 2  with different Models and Controllers, but one is working and other is not working. Disabling any of the Controller will work fine, but both are not working together, even i have declared different variables.

```js
var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []); 
        app1.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) 
     {
  $scope.firstName1= "FirstName MyApp1_MyConrl1    ";
  $scope.lastName1= "LastName MyApp1_MyConrl1";
     });


        var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []); 
        app2.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) 
     {
    $scope.firstName2= "FirstName MyApp2_MyConrl2   ";
    $scope.lastName2= "LastName MyApp2_MyConrl2";
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">

        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName1"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName1"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName1 + " " + lastName1}}

        </div>

        <div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">

        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName2"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName2"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName2 + " " + lastName2}}

        </div>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);    
    app1.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) 
    {
    $scope.firstName1= "FirstName MyApp1_MyConrl1    ";
    $scope.lastName1= "LastName MyApp1_MyConrl1";
    });        is working but the other one is not.

Comment: Why are you using two differents apps in the same application? I can't see a reason to do that.

Comment: so is that a wrong approach?

Comment: Yeah, for sure, you should use a single application and create two different controllers. I'll answer with a JSFiddle, so you can check.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Angular document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp):

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead

you can only have one `ngApp` attribute per HTML document:

```
<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName1"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName1"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName1 + " " + lastName1}}

</div>

<div id="#app2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName2"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName2"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName2 + " " + lastName2}}

</div>
```

And you should manually bootstrap the second angular application:

```
var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);    
app1.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.firstName1= "FirstName MyApp1_MyConrl1";
    $scope.lastName1= "LastName MyApp1_MyConrl1";
});


var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);    
app2.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.firstName2= "FirstName MyApp2_MyConrl2   ";
    $scope.lastName2= "LastName MyApp2_MyConrl2";
});
angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector("#app2"), ['myApp2']);
```

Answer (score 1):

since there is no answer on this topic, i researched and found that we can create only **one** ng-app but **multiple** controllers
Here is the example (Please have a look on my previous code from question to compare it with new one)
New Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">                  </script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName1"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName1"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName1 + " " + lastName1}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName2"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName2"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName2 + " " + lastName2}}
</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var onlyOneApp = angular.module('myApp', []);   
onlyOneApp.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) 
{$scope.firstName1= "";
$scope.lastName1= "";
}); 
onlyOneApp.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) 
{$scope.firstName2= "";
$scope.lastName2= "";
});
</script>
```

Comment: i apologies to everyone who did not understand my requirements. just run the code as it is. thanks